# style is not applied on div while it's on different one

Tags: html, css, bootstrapper

I have following styles

```
.MapField {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
}
.MapTab
{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
}
div[worldTexture="1"] {
    background:url(../WorldTextures/dirt.jpg);
}
```

Then I have following html fragment

```
<div class="col-xs-9 MapTab">
  <div class="col-xs-6 MapField" worldTexture="1"/>
  <div class="col-xs-6 MapField" worldTexture="1"/>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3"></div>
```

Then I'd expect both `col-xs-6` will have height at least `70px` (in case screen size allows that) but it leads to `div` with size like `width:70px height:1px` 
changing `.MapStyle` to have `width` and `height` `!important` does not change anything

On the other hand, in case I change usage of `div` to `table` in following way

```
td[worldTexture="1"] {
    background:url(../WorldTextures/dirt.jpg);
}

<table>
<tr class="col-xs-9 MapTab">
  <td class="col-xs-6 MapField" worldTexture="1"/>
  <td class="col-xs-6 MapField" worldTexture="1"/>
</tr>
<tr class="col-xs-3"></div>
<table>
```

it works as expected, any idea what may go wrong here?

Comment: If you stick with `<div>` I think `max-width:70px;` on `.mapField` will do the trick

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I'm struggling with height but now even max-height:70px; on .mapField didn't trick unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think those divs should be self-closing tags.

Try

```
<div class="col-xs-9 MapTab">
  <div class="col-xs-6 MapField" worldTexture="1"></div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 MapField" worldTexture="1"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-3"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I gave it try but no effect unfortunately. Honestly I'd expect having or not having it self-closing should be syntactic sugar for html renderer in case that div is empty anyway and thought it should not affect it.

Comment: There may be something else at play that I'm not seeing, but I do get different behavior with self-closing div tags on my end: https://codepen.io/rachidmrad/pen/rjJYOO

Comment: At the end I found out that problem was totally elswhere, not related to CSS at all. Anyway snippet you've linked was interesting and I'd say it could be solution in different case. Thanks for effort.